# Continuity of functions through successions

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve this exercise, but I have difficulties to realize the proof.

Let $S$ a subset of real numbers and $f\colon S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $a \in S$. Suppose $f$ has the property

If $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $S$ such that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$ then $(f(x_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

Prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$.

My attempt!: I tried to relate the sequence $(x_n) \rightarrow a$ with the constant sequence $(a)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow a$ in the following way:

Let be $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}= \begin{cases} x_n, & n=2k+1\\a, & n=2k \end{cases}$

It's clear that $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $a$, in both cases, whether $n$ is even or odd, then $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence, thus for every $ \epsilon >0$ exist a natural number $N$ such that if $n,m>N$ then $|f(y_n)-f(y_m)|< \epsilon$, if $m=2k$ then $\lvert f(x_n)-f(a)\rvert< \epsilon$. Thus $f$ is continuous at $a$.

The problem is that I can't establish conditions between $n$ and $m$. Any help would be appreciated or if there is a simpler way to do the proof of the exercise, please tell me. Thanks and regards!

Comment: You already have a complete and rigorous proof. I cannot understand what you mean by conditions between $n$ and $m$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You mean that this completes the exercise and you do not need to see what happens if $m$ is odd?

Comment: Yes, you can choose m to be even and n to be odd to prove that $f(x_n) \to f(a)$. No need to consider other cases.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the clarification.